# Custom module with custom node type, error Trying to get property of non-object en comment_node_type_delete()

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm quite new with Drupal 7 development, after researching and following some tutorials I was able to create my custom module that defines a new node type with some fields, but now I have a problem when I uninstall it, the hook_uninstall runs almost fine(the node type, the contents from my custom node, and the node fields), except that display this error after the uninstall:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object en
>   comment_node_type_delete() (línea 344 de
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/modules/comment/comment.module). Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object en comment_node_type_delete()
>   (línea 355 de
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/modules/comment/comment.module). Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object en comment_node_type_delete()
>   (línea 355 de
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/modules/comment/comment.module). Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object en comment_node_type_delete()
>   (línea 355 de
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/modules/comment/comment.module). Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object en comment_node_type_delete()
>   (línea 355 de
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/modules/comment/comment.module). Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object en comment_node_type_delete()
>   (línea 355 de
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/modules/comment/comment.module). Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object en comment_node_type_delete()
>   (línea 355 de
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/modules/comment/comment.module). Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object en comment_node_type_delete()
>   (línea 355 de
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/modules/comment/comment.module).

This is from mymodule.install:

```
function mynode_uninstall() {

    $ournewtype = 'mynode';
    $sql = 'SELECT nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = :type';
    $result = db_query($sql, array(':type' => $ournewtype));
    $nodeids = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $nodeids[] = $row->nid;
    }
    node_delete_multiple($nodeids);
    node_type_delete($ournewtype);
    field_purge_batch(500);
    drupal_flush_all_caches();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that it's expecting an object, and you are passing a string. Try changing this:

```
node_type_delete($ournewtype);
```

To this:

```
$node_type = node_type_load($ournewtype);
node_type_delete($node_type);
```

One other thing, instead of this:

```
$result = db_query($sql, array(':type' => $ournewtype));
$nodeids = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $nodeids[] = $row->nid;
}
```

You can simplify it by using this:

```
$nodeids = db_query($sql, array(':type' => $ournewtype))->fetchCol();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, tested but the error still persist.

Comment: Also, with that modification, hook_uninstall doesn't delete the node type and node fields.

Comment: I believe that the problem si because node_type_load doesn't load if because the module is already disable and thats why doesn't delete the node type, but i'm not shure, still quite new in this stuff. I wasn't able to fix it.